# Should it be "many other prizes" or "many more prizes"

Tags: grammaticality

When advertising prizes in a Christmas raffle, should we use "and many other prizes" or "and many more prizes" after listing the 3 top prizes in the draw?

Comment: The real question is whether anyone reading it would discern a meaningful difference.

Comment: What's the full sentence/context?

Answer (score 1):

Use many “other” if you can win this OR that; many “more” if you can win this AND [many more prizes].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).